# Is there anyway to get the UDID of a booted simulator in mac via terminal

Tags: appium-ios

Trying to start Appium server for different Ipad Simulators but when i use the below Command

`xcrun simctl list | egrep '(Booted)'`

i get the complete detail of the Booted Simulator

```
iPad (5th generation) (1D9E3D9C-7715-4742-A9DC-6096BCE95B64) (Booted)
```

is there any way to get only the UDID of the simulator which is Booted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using `awk` or equivalent to grab just the `UDID` info:

```
xcrun simctl list | awk -F'[()]' '/(Booted)/ { print $4 }'
```

You might need to adjust the number that outputs the field (so instead of `$4`, it might be `$3`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you it's working has i want Just need to Change it to $4
Can you tell me the site where i can find stuff

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
xcrun simctl list devices | grep "(Booted)" | grep -E -o -i "([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})"
```